# In Lyx, I need to make the part* to be at the right side

Tags: xetex, lyx

Is there any command of the sort: \renewcommand XXXX that I can write  to make the part*(un-numbered) to be written at the right side of the page?

Comment: You can try loading `titlesec`  and code in the preamble `\titleformat*{\part}{\raggedleft}`.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\part}[display]{\filleft\huge\bfseries}{\part\space\thepart}{2ex}{}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think you meant ``\partname`` instead of ``\part``, in the third mandatory argument of ``\titleformat``. Also, on this site it is always better to provide a complete, compilable example when answering a question.

Comment: You are right, Im rather new to the TeX enviroment. thank you.